# How to pass Selenium object to another class?

Tags: python, class, selenium

Im having trouble calling my original selenium instance in my 2nd class which has a function GetRows(). What are the ways i can get the selenium object in my Functions Class?

```
Class test(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.verificationerrors=[]
        self.selenium = selenium("localhost",4444,"","http://localhost")
        self.selenium.start()

    def test_untitiled(self):
        pass

    def teardown(self):
        pass

    def Get(self):     
        return self.selenium

Class Functions:
    def GetRows(self)
        selenium.get_xpath_count(path)   //Cant call selenium object here! :(
        sel = test().get()   // Does not allow me to return self. selenium :(
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second class either extend or instantiate your "test" class, which is responsible for creation of Selenium object

Comment: As a Selenium Core Committer I can't suggest anyone uses SQA StackExchange. -1

Comment: As a core Selenium Doc Member, I suppose I did not do any thing wrong.     Have you seen this? - http://meta.sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/13/how-would-we-attract-selenium-users-to-ask-question-on-sqa-site-than-on-stackovef                                                                 And above all how could this be a reason to mark response as -1 ?

Answer (score 0):

The way that I would do it is to abstract all that you need to do to your second class and have your test just calling that.

So your test class would look like this

```
class SearchTests(unittest.TestCase):

    _count_regex = '^.* (\d+) - (\d+)'
    _total_count_regex = '^.* \d+ - \d+ of (\d+)'

    def setUp(self):
        self.selenium = selenium(server, 
                                port,
                                browser, 
                                baseurl)
        self.selenium.start()
        self.selenium.set_timeout(ConnectionParameters.page_load_timeout)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.selenium.stop()

    def test_that_character_escaping_doesnt_go_into_the_test(self):
        """ Test for Litmus 4857
            https://litmus.mozilla.org/show_test.cgi?id=4857"""
        amo_home_page = AddonsHomePage(self.selenium)
        amo_search_page = amo_home_page.search_for("personas%20plus")
        self.assertTrue(amo_search_page.is_text_present("No results found."))
        results_count = amo_search_page.results_count
        self.assertTrue("0 - 0 of 0" in results_count)
```

And your abstraction would look something like this

```
class AddonsSearchHomePage(AddonsHomePage):

    _results_count_header = "css=h3.results-count"
    _page_counter = "css=div.num-results"

    def __init__(self, selenium):
        self.selenium = selenium

    @property
    def results_count(self):
        return self.selenium.get_text(self._results_count_header)

    @property
    def page_results_count(self):
        return self.selenium.get_text(self._page_counter)
```

You can see a whole project like that at https://github.com/AutomatedTester/Addon-Tests